# how to make section grid in android

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I have to create list of gridview like section gridview where it has title and grid items below, i achieved this by using recyclerview and gridview, but the issue is, scroll doesn't goes smoother, it gives zerk while scrolling. and then i tried with recyclerview, cardview, along with GridLayoutManager, but now i'm not able to set background to the section. please see the attached image, you will get idea on what i am trying. 
suggest me which are the best approach to set background without using gridview and listview combination.

[image]

Comment: you cannot use gridView for this.but you can create images dynamically and give it's layout parameters according to the pattern.

Comment: Hi, i am not using gridview now, i changed my implementation. now i am trying with recyclerview and cardviews, i have two different cards for title and item, but i am not able to achieve to group them as single section with background set.

Comment: That is why it's better for you to create images dynamically and assign IDs and tags for ease access